# pl/sql save as

Tags: sql, plsql

hi im from madrid and i wanted to know how to save a query/cursor, in a XXXXXXX.sql.

thanks!!!

Comment: Hi I'm from Canberra and I don't understand your question.  Do you want to save the results of the query?

Comment: also, saving the results of a query that you are running through, say, SQLPlus, is very different than saving the results of a cursor you are using in a PL/SQL block.

Comment: Hi, I'm from Perth. I tend to use notepad, or a SQL editor if one's handy. Type the query in, choose File -> Save As from the menu, and type XXXXXXX.sql
:)

Comment: If it's the results of a query you're after, you might want to specify which database software you're using.

Comment: im using TOAD 9 and i want to save the result of a query and later send it to a folder online in EXCEL.....

Comment: I'm pretty sure TOAD has a "Save As Excel" function for query result grids.

Answer (score 1):

well, Toad has a save as function.
Run your query, right=click in the datagrid and choose Save As.  You'll get a screen of options.